# Elasticsearch Nest 5 QueryContainer acts differently

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Since upgrading from Nest 1.7 to 5 my pattern for creating query classes that I used to use no longer works and I was wondering if someone could point out why or how I can change so that it does.

Firstly I have a base class that my query classes inherit from:

```
public abstract class BaseSearchQuery<T> : SearchDescriptor<T>
    where T : class
{
    protected QueryContainer SearchQueryContainer;

    protected void AndQuery(QueryContainer query)
    {
        SearchQueryContainer = SearchQueryContainer == null 
                ? query
                : SearchQueryContainer && query;
    }

    protected abstract SearchDescriptor<T> Build();
}
```

Then I'd inherit from this class for each different query I wanted to make:

```
public class SomeSearch : BaseSearchQuery<SomeType>
{
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }

    protected override SearchDescriptor<SomeType> Build()
    {
        return AddSomeValue()
            .Query(SearchQueryContainer);
    }

    private SomeSearch AddSomeValue()
    {
        AndQuery(new QueryDescriptor<SomeType>().Term(f => f.SomeField.Suffix("raw"), SomeValue));
        return this;
    }
}
```

Since upgrading NEST this no longer works, if anyone knows how to get this working or a better way of doing this I'd be so grateful.

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-queries.html) NEST docs about bulding bool queries? Looks legit, maybe will help you.

Comment: Yes, doesn't help me, I'm trying to create a reusable and clean way to create queries, that page didn't help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since upgrading from Nest 1.7 to 5 my pattern for creating query classes that I used to use no longer works

How does it no longer work? There are a few small changes needed to type names, but this works

```
public abstract class BaseSearchQuery<T> : SearchDescriptor<T>
    where T : class
{
    protected QueryContainer SearchQueryContainer;

    protected void AndQuery(QueryContainer query)
    {
        SearchQueryContainer = SearchQueryContainer == null
                ? query
                : SearchQueryContainer && query;
    }

    protected abstract SearchDescriptor<T> Build();
}

public class SomeSearch : BaseSearchQuery<SomeType>
{
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }

    protected override SearchDescriptor<SomeType> Build()
    {
        return AddSomeValue()
            .Query(_ => SearchQueryContainer);
    }

    private SomeSearch AddSomeValue()
    {   
        AndQuery(new QueryContainerDescriptor<SomeType>().Term(f => f.SomeField.Suffix("raw"), SomeValue));
        return this;
    }
}
```

I'm not really seeing what this query class pattern is really providing you though; I can see it as a way of encapsulating common queries that are called from different places within the solution, but perhaps the `Query<T>` static class methods can help here, and encapsulate these in a static class for a specific POCO type, to be reused in different places?

```
public class SomeType
{
    public string SomeField { get; set; }
}

public static class SomeTypeQueries
{
    public static QueryContainer SomeFieldRawTerm(string value) =>
        Query<SomeType>.Term(f => f.SomeField.Suffix("raw"), value);
}

var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

client.Search<SomeType>(s => s.Query(_ => SomeTypeQueries.SomeFieldRawTerm("term")));
```

Comment: The pattern allowed flexibility in what properties were searched on, there were normally many AddSomeValue() methods that accepted different values etc.